# Html return did not work after I added the return false

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I want to submit the `username` and `email` to a file called `welcome.php`, it used to work , but after adding return `false` to prevent some problems on registering, even though it satisfy every requirement that I've set, it didn't go to the `php` file!

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var passw_1 = document.myform.password1.value;
            var passw_2 = document.myform.password2.value;
            if (passw_1 != passw_2) {
                alert("You didn't enter the same password.");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            var sletter = document.myform.email.value;
            var reg = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+((\.[a-zA-Z0- 
                9 _ - ] {
                2,
                3
            }) {
            1,
            2
        }) $ / );
        test_email = reg.test(sletter);
        if (test_email != true) {
            alert("not correct form of email ！");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        if (document.myform.password1.value == "") alert("The password should 
            not be empty.
            ");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myform" action="welcome.php" method="post" name="register">
        <p>First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></p>
        <p>password: <input name="password1" id="pswl1" type="text" /></p>
        <p>confirm your password: <input name="password2" id="pswl2" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">other
        <br/> Music
        <input type="checkbox" name="Hobby" value="music" onclick="chose(this)" /> Theater
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="chose(this)" name="Hobby" value="theater" />
        <br/> Sports
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="chose(this)" name="Hobby" value="sports" /> Dancing
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="chose(this)" name="Hobby" value="dancing" />
        <p> </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return myFunction()" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your my function you are not returning true or false, if all requirements satisfied then return true try this and let me know it's working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue while using `event.preventDefault();` as `event` never defined in your script. Instead of it try to `return false`

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var passw_1 = document.myform.password1.value;
        var passw_2 = document.myform.password2.value;
        if (passw_1 != passw_2) {
            alert("You didn't enter the same password.");
            return false; //event.preventDefault();
        }
        var sletter = document.myform.email.value;
        var reg = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+((\.[a-zA-Z0- 
            9 _ - ] {
            2,
            3
        }) {
        1,
        2
    }) $ / );
    test_email = reg.test(sletter);
    if (test_email != true) {
        alert("not correct form of email ！");
        return false; //event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (document.myform.password1.value == "") alert("The password should 
        not be empty.
        ");
        return false; //event.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone

I've solved that!!!

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var passw_1 = document.myform.password1.value;
var passw_2 = document.myform.password2.value;
var sletter =document.myform.email.value; 
var reg =new RegExp( /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+((\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,3}){1,2})$/);
test_email=reg.test(sletter);

if(passw_1 != passw_2){ 
alert("You didn't enter the same password.");
return false ; 
}
else if(test_email!=true) {  
alert("not correct form of email ！"); 
return false; 
}
else if(document.myform.password1.value =="") {
alert("The password should not be empty.");
return false; 
}
else{return true;}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="welcome.php" method="post" name="register" onSubmit ="return myFunction()">
<p>First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></p>
<p>password: <input  name="password1" id="pswl1"  type="text"  /></p>
<p>confirm your password: <input name="password2" id="pswl2" type="text"  />
</p>
<p>email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" >other
<br/>  
Music<input type="checkbox" name="Hobby" value="music" 
onclick="chose(this)" />         
Theater<input type="checkbox" onclick="chose(this)" name="Hobby" 
value="theater"/> 
<br/>  
Sports<input type="checkbox" onclick="chose(this)" name="Hobby" value="sports"/>  
Dancing<input type="checkbox" onclick="chose(this)" name="Hobby" value="dancing"/>  
<p> </p> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```